# Extjs rest proxy is not appending the record ID to the url

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, proxy

In my Extjs project I have a model with a rest proxy defined:

```
Ext.define('Registration.model.Session', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        ...
    ],
    proxy:{
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/sessions',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'records'
        }
    }
});
```

When I create a store that uses this model and try to do a GET request for a particular record id, the id is not being appended to the url for some reason:

[image: Screen shot of problem]

I was reading back through [the rest proxy's docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) and it seems like this is all I needed to do to make a get call for a particular record.

I've not specified the `appendId` config in the proxy so it should be set to the default value of true.

Is there a config I'm missing on the proxy to append the id?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. That was a goof on my part. I was calling the load method on the store and the proxy I defined is on the model.

I pulled out the model and fired it's load method with the record ID and it worked:

[image]

## I should point out that I don't think this is the best way of getting this record.

So if anyone has a better suggestion I'm all ears ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can also define proxies on models.  I didnt realize it at first, but my team uses sencha architect and I noticed that there were the settings to connect it all up there under the model too so I tried it one day and it worked.

After I saw it in Sencha Architect, I also went back to the APIs on the site and sure enough its there too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you defined idProperty: 'Id' in your model. If not try this.